# Permissions when using escpos in virtualenv

Tags: linux, python-3.x, escpos

Using Debian, Install escpos, to be able to print on an Epson TM-T20II printer, and I have an application on python3. The problem I have is when I send to print it generates the following error:

```
File "/media/palma/Proyectos/Django/parqueadero/virtual/lib/python3.4/site-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 595, in _check
  raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)
```

For which the file /etc/udev/rules.d/99-escpos.rule was created

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0e15", MODE="0666", GROUP="dialout"
```

The order to print is given in this way:

```
from escpos.printer import Usb

p = Usb(0x04b8, 0x0202)
p.text("Hello World\n")
```

When I do it as a root user, it prints correctly

Answer (score 0):

In your udev rule, change 'MODE="0666", GROUP="dialout"' to 'MODE:="0666", GROUP:="dialout" and it will setup mode and group ownership correctly.

Comment: I make the change as you indicate but the problem continues :(

Comment: Did you restart the system or re-trigger udev?

Comment: Yes, I restart the computer